# Redirect website URL without the .html ending

Tags: html, .htaccess, redirect

So I have a URL that I want people to end up on www.website.com/folder/file
The problem is that the URL written on these flyers is something different, www.website/file.

I created a file for www.website/file with a working redirect but people must type in www.website/file.html for the redirect to work. I'd like them to able to type JUST www.website/file without the .html

Anyway this can work? As of now the redirect is using html and working fine. My other possibility is editing my .htaccess file. I am working for a company with coldfusion and I don't see a .htaccess file (hidden files visible) so I'm weary to throw one in there as I fear it might screw something up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could rename the file.html as index.html and  that should suffice.

E-g; www.domain.com/folder/folder/file.html   is same as  www.domain.com/folder/folder/

if file.html is called as index.html

Comment: This did it! Simply giving the folder the name I needed for the URL and then putting an index file IN that folder with the redirect. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There are few different options to solve this, but one of them could be just making a separate folder named "file" and adding there a index.html file.

Answer (score 0):

If possible, I would go for the .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteRule ^/file$ /folder/file [R]
</IfModule>
```

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule